# Arithmetic operation (Difference) between a vector and a Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, arithmetic-expressions

I am facing this issue when I am trying to calculate the difference between list and matrix in R, it is giving me weird results.

```
matrix <- matrix(1:10,1:10,nrow = 10,ncol=10)

list1 <- seq(1:10)

diff <- list1-matrix
```

Below is the output that I am trying to achieve but it does not work. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You showed a `vector` and not a `list`.  You can do this in many ways `t(t(matrix)- list1)`  or `matrix - list1[col(matrix)]` or `sweep(matrix, 2, list1, `-`)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with multiple ways

**1**) Transpose the matrix, subtract from the `vector` and then do the `transpose`

```
t(t(matrix)- list1)
```

**2**) replicate the `vector` to make the lengths same and then do the difference

```
matrix - list1[col(matrix)]
```

**3**) Using `sweep`

```
sweep(matrix, 2, list1, `-`)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that in R matrices are stored in column-major order. This means that a matrix is a sequence of numbers order by columns from top to down.

So when you subtract a vector from a matrix you can imagine it as operation with 4 steps:

1. matrix is turned into a sequence of numbers (a vector)
2. your "list1" is expanded (repeated) so that it's length matches the length of the vector constructed from the matrix.
3. the elements in each are subtracted from each other
4. the numbers are assembled into the matrix form again.

In your case:

1) matrix is turned into a sequence of numbers (by columns) giving you:

```
1, 1, 1 ,1 ... 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, ... 2, ... ... 10, 10, 10, 10, ... 10
```

2) Your second vector is repeated until it matches the first one:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8, 9, 10, ... 1, 2, 3, ... 10
```

3) Now both of them have the same length so they are subtracted from each other:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ..., -9, -8, -7, ... 0
```

4) The result is transformed into a matrix again giving you the matrix that you see.

In order to obtain your desired result you have to take this into account. One way is to transpose your matrix, do the subtraction, and transpose it back again:

```
t(t(matrix) - list1)
```

This works because after the transpose `t` the rows are turned into columns.

Another approach is to construct a matrix out of your list1 vector:

```
matrix2 <- matrix(list1, nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE)
```

And then do the subtraction:

```
diff <- matrix - matrix2
```